# File output in current working directory truncated

Tags: c, directory, mingw

I run this program to output the contents of the current working directory.  I get the wrong output.  Program is listed below with the output I get posted after it.

**code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>



int main ()
{
DIR *gdir = NULL;
gdir = opendir(".");

struct dirent *hdir = NULL;

//hdir.d_ino = 123;
//hdir->d_name[256] = NULL;

if (gdir == NULL)
{
    printf ("Could not open directory.");
    exit (3);
}

while ( hdir = readdir(gdir) )
{       
    if (hdir == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Could not read from directory.");
        //printf ("%d\n", i);
        exit (3);
        //printf ("hdir.d_ino: %ld", hdir.d_ino);

    }
    else
    {
        printf ("Name:  %25s\n", hdir->d_name);
    }

    //i++;
}
//printf ("%d\n", i);

closedir(gdir);
//printf ("hdir.d_reclen: %u", hdir.d_reclen);
system ("PAUSE");

return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
Name:
Name:
Name:
Name:
Name:                    ry.c
```

Notice the `ry.c` file with the `.c` file extension.  That is one of the files in the current working directory.  I do not understand why only one truncated file name is outputted where the other files are not.

**platform details**

I have the current mingw installation, compiling with gcc, on windows 8.  I am using Windows command line to compile.

Comment: also post the file names in that directory ( `dir` )

Comment: Does the program work for you amdixon?  Do the contents of your directory output correctly?

Comment: Besides `PAUSE` most likely is unknow/undefined the code looks okay.

Comment: @alk can you explain why these is not output and the ry.c is truncated?

Comment: Are those file's name containing any characters different from ASCII?

Comment: @alk No.  The file's names are ASCII values.  Should I check for ASCII values by inserting a C function to determine if they are ASCII values in the while loop?

Comment: I output the d_ino value printf ("%d\n", hdir->d_ino); and the value comes back as a 0.  The d_ino is the file serial number for struct dirent.  Why is it zero?  Could this be related to the incorrect output from my program?

Comment: I am convinced now it is a bad dirent.h file included with mingw.  I do not know how to resolve this.  Any suggestions from anyone?

Comment: I found this as a possible solution:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554325/readdir-32-64-compatibility-issues